# Arduino PID Library

Tags: arduino-uno, functions, pid

I hope you're doing well. I have some questions regarding the PID functions.

Can you please explain to me the following commands? I shall be very thankful to you.

- `PID myPIDX(&InputX, &OutputX, &SetpointX, Kpx, Kix, Kdx, REVERSE);`
  What is meant by reverse and why we used & with input, output and setpoint?
- `myPIDX.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);`
  What is meant by automatic/manual?
- `myPIDX.SetOutputLimits(80, 110)`
  What is meant by the values 80, 110 and what is range 0-255?
- `myPIDX.SetSampleTime(45);`
  What is meant by this command? is the time in milli-seconds?
- `myPIDX.Compute();`
  How is this function working? I mean what is happening at the back end of the compute function?

Best Regards!

Comment: The library documentation and/or code would be the best place to start. At the very least a link to the library you're asking about would be helpful.

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIDLibrary

Comment: This is the link to this library I'm talking about

Comment: Can you guide me related to this? My project is 2 DOF Ball Balancing using a PID controller

Comment: The documentation seems to explain at least some of these fairly well. The code for each is available as well.

Comment: Yea ive done the code

Comment: I need to understand the backend work being done behind these

Comment: Then you'll need to read the code?